# Docker & Rails | bundler: command not found: rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler

I'm brand new to Docker and fairly new to Rails.

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get this error:

```
web_1  | bundler: command not found: rails
web_1  | Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
app_web_1 exited with code 127
```

Initially I had trouble getting it to find any gem when running `bundle install`. I was getting a "*Could not find gem in any of the sources*" error for every single Gem in my Gemfile. I then attempted to run `bundle` (without `install`) and it returned no errors.

Rails is definitely installed, as typing `rails` gives me all of it's usage options.

Also, I can see the gems in `vendor/cache`. I tried removing all of them and running `bundle install` and they all start appearing one by one as the bundler installs them.

**EDIT:** Please feel free to correct my understanding: since running bundle install is meant to install the gems on the Docker instance, it is not being installed "locally". While attempting to troubleshoot this issue, I deleted all my gems locally and re-installed bundler. So, when I run `gems list`, I only see bundler. I ran `bundler install` and it claims that all the gems are being installed. Where are they being installed? It says it's going to vendor/cache, and that's true. I can see them there, yet it still fails to find any gems: it won't even find rails.

**EDIT 2:** I should also mention: `bin/rails s` starts the server just fine. It won't load anything due to the database instance not running, but that makes sense I guess.

**EDIT 3:** I ran `gem install rails` locally, still no change but now `gems list` returns rails and its dependencies.

Below are some files and logs that may be relevant below and could help determine the cause. Please note I changed the actual application name to `app`.

**Running `gems list` returns this:**

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (5.1.1)
actionpack (5.1.1)
actionview (5.1.1)
activejob (5.1.1)
activemodel (5.1.1)
activerecord (5.1.1)
activesupport (5.1.1)
arel (8.0.0)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.15.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
erubi (1.6.0)
globalid (0.4.0)
i18n (0.8.1)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.5)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.2)
nio4r (2.0.0)
nokogiri (1.7.2)
rack (2.0.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.1.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.1.1)
rake (12.0.0)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
thor (0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tzinfo (1.2.3)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
```

**My Gemfile looks like this:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'gmail'

gem 'oauth', '0.5.2'

gem 'twilio'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**My `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:**

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**My `Dockerfile` looks like this:**

```
FROM ruby:2.4.0
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD Gemfile /app/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock
ADD . /app
```

**Running `bundle install` returns this:**

```
Using rake 12.0.0
Using oauth 0.5.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using builder 3.2.3
Using multi_xml 0.6.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 0.8.1
Using minitest 5.10.2
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 2.0.3
Using nio4r 2.0.0
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using arel 7.1.4
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using bundler 1.15.0
Using pg 0.20.0
Using puma 3.8.2
Using sass 3.4.24
Using tilt 2.0.7
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.3
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using ffi 1.9.18
Using gmail_xoauth 0.4.2
Using mime-types 3.1
Using httparty 0.15.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.3
Using nokogiri 1.7.2
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using websocket-driver 0.6.5
Using uglifier 3.2.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using rb-inotify 0.9.8
Using mail 2.6.5
Using twilio 3.1.1
Using activesupport 5.0.3
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using listen 3.0.8
Using gmail 0.6.0
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using globalid 0.4.0
Using activemodel 5.0.3
Using jbuilder 2.6.4
Using spring 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using activejob 5.0.3
Using activerecord 5.0.3
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using actionview 5.0.3
Using actionpack 5.0.3
Using actioncable 5.0.3
Using actionmailer 5.0.3
Using railties 5.0.3
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
Using web-console 3.5.1
Using rails 5.0.3
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Updating files in vendor/cache
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/cache.
```

Comment: Can you clarify where you are running your test commands? It sounds like you are building an image, it doesn't work, but you proceed to test `rails` and other command on your local machine (not inside the container). You will still need to have the `RUN bundle install` step in your `Dockerfile` to install all the gems in the image.

Comment: @AndyShinn Yup I figured it out before you commented, see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure if this is a proper solution, but I tried adding

```
RUN bundler install
```

to my `Dockerfile`. I deleted all of the images, ran `docker-compose up` and worked like a charm.

Comment: This is the proper solution. Basically bundler isn't installed by default on the ruby image.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution that worked for me is to create a `docker-entrypoint.sh` file in the root of your project similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5
```

and add this steps in your `Dockerfile`

```
# allows a shell script to run before any relative containers execute a command.
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

This way you have the possibility to run this shellscript file around the initialization of your container. You can read more about this here: https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone facing a similar issue. This might help.
Docker env you may want to set up your bundler specific case.
For example:
Use system folder for bundler and gems

```
# Docker file
ENV BUNDLE_PATH="/usr/local/bundle"
ENV GEM_HOME="/usr/local/bundle/gems"
ENV GEM_PATH="/usr/local/bundle/gems"
```

Or you can use vendor if you loading in your source code into Dockerfile.

```
ENV BUNDLE_PATH="vendor/bundle"
ENV BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=".bundle"
```

And please check out this article from bundler team.
https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_docker_guide.html